# In what order are non-static data members initialized?

Tags: c++, initialization, datamember, order-of-execution, class-members

In the following code, when the ctor of `X` is called will the ctor of `A` or `B` be called first? Does the order in which they are placed in the body of the class control this? If somebody can provide a snippet of text from the C++ standard that talks about this issue, that would be perfect.

```
class A {};
class B {};
class X
{
 A a;
 B b;
};
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The order is the order they appear in the class definition - this is from section 12.6.2 of the C++ Standard:

> 5 Initialization shall proceed in the
> following order:
>
> — First, and only for
> the constructor of the most derived
> class as described below, virtual base
> classes shall be initialized in the
> order they appear on a depth-first
> left-to-right traversal of the
> directed acyclic graph of base
> classes, where “left-to-right” is the
> order of appearance of the base class
> names in the derived class
> base-specifier-list.
>
> — Then, direct
> base classes shall be initialized in
> declaration order as they appear in
> the base-specifier-list (regardless of
> the order of the mem-initializers).
>
> — Then, nonstatic data members shall be
> initialized in the order they were
> declared in the class definition
> (again regardless of the order of the
> mem-initializers).
>
> — Finally, the body
> of the constructor is executed. [Note:
> the declaration order is mandated to
> ensure that base and member subobjects
> are destroyed in the reverse order of
> initialization. ]

Comment: Where does member data list initiation fall?

Answer (score 15):

Initialization is always in the order that the class members appear in your class definition, so in your example `a`, then `b`.

There is a sequence point between the initialization of each member and you *can* pass a reference to a yet-to-be initialized member into the constructor of a class member but you would only be able to use it in limited ways (such as taking its address to form a pointer), other uses may well cause undefined behaviour.

Destruction of class members always happens in the reverse order of construction.

Order of initialization of bases and members is defined in 12.6.2 [class.base.init]/5.

Comment: Could you provide a reference?

Comment: To add to this, if you have a constructor for X like this - X(): b(), a() {} a is still initialized first.

Comment: I know this. I am asking for a reference. I confidently said this to someone who asked for a reference and I could not find one. Hence the question.

Comment: @Nikhil: I was just checking the para number. Now added.

Comment: @Nikhil: If you know this then why ask the question? Why not just ask for a reference instead of asking about something that you already know as well?

Comment: @Nikhil: I don't think anybody would expect you to remember reference locations into the standard. Just know where to look it up; you're unlikely to need to know the exact reference often.