# Declaration of cross-recursive rules

Tags: c++, recursion, static, boost-spirit, forward-declaration

I declared rules of my grammar as static const. That worked fine till I tried to use cross-recursive rules (*rule1* is defined using *rule2* which is defined using *rule1*). The source code still can be built, but segfaults on parsing source containing such cross-recursive case.
Here's a simplified code of the grammar:

```
template < typename Iterator >
class Skipper : public qi::grammar<Iterator> {
public:
    Skipper ( ) : Skipper::base_type(_skip_rule) { }
private:
    static qi::rule<Iterator> const
        _comment,
        _skip_rule;
};

template < typename Iterator >
typename qi::rule<Iterator> const
    Skipper<Iterator>::_comment(
        boost::spirit::repository::confix("/*", "*/")[*(qi::char_ - "*/")]          // Multi-line
        | boost::spirit::repository::confix("//", qi::eol)[*(qi::char_ - qi::eol)]   // Single-line
    );

template < typename Iterator >
typename qi::rule<Iterator> const
     Skipper<Iterator>::_skip_rule(qi::ascii::space | _comment);

template < typename Iterator, typename Skipper >
class Grammar : public qi::grammar<Iterator, Skipper > {
public:
    Grammar ( ) : Grammar::base_type(expression) { }
private:
    static qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> const
        // Tokens
        scalar_literal,
        identifier,
        // Rules
        operand,
        expression;
};

template < typename Iterator, typename Skipper >
typename qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> const
    Grammar<Iterator, Skipper>::scalar_literal(qi::uint_ | qi::int_);

template < typename Iterator, typename Skipper >
typename qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> const
    Grammar<Iterator, Skipper>::identifier(qi::lexeme[(qi::alpha | '_') >> *(qi::alnum | '_')]);

template < typename Iterator, typename Skipper >
typename qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> const
    Grammar<Iterator, Skipper>::operand((scalar_literal | identifier | ('(' >> expression >> ')')));

template < typename Iterator, typename Skipper >
typename qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> const
    Grammar<Iterator, Skipper>::expression(operand);
```

(*expression* rule is made identical to *operand* to make the code easier to understand; of course it should be more complicated yet based on *operand*). *operand* declaration uses *expression* one and vice versa. That segfaults when trying to *parse_phrase* for example (123). I suppose that it's because of "forward" using of *expression*; same happens if I put *expression* declaration before the *operand* one. So in what way should these rules be declared to avoid runtime error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First off, the static has nothing to do with it:

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20ca33b88ac764b7)</kbd>** fails just as badly:

   ```
   #include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
   #include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi.hpp>

   namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

   template <typename Iterator>
   struct Skipper : qi::grammar<Iterator> {
       Skipper() : Skipper::base_type(_skip_rule) { }
   private:
       qi::rule<Iterator> const
           _comment { 
               boost::spirit::repository::confix("/*", "*/")    [*(qi::char_ - "*/")]     // Multi-line
           | boost::spirit::repository::confix("//", qi::eol) [*(qi::char_ - qi::eol)]  // Single-line
           },
           _skip_rule {
               qi::ascii::space | _comment
           };
   };

   template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
   struct Grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, Skipper> {
       Grammar() : Grammar::base_type(expression) { }
   private:
       qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> const
           // Tokens
           scalar_literal { qi::uint_ | qi::int_ },
           identifier     { qi::lexeme[(qi::alpha | '_') >> *(qi::alnum | '_')] },
           // Rules
           operand        { (scalar_literal | identifier | ('(' >> expression >> ')')) },
           expression     { operand };
   };

   int main() {
       using It = std::string::const_iterator;
       Skipper<It> s;
       Grammar<It, Skipper<It> > p;
       std::string const input = "(123)";

       It f = input.begin(), l = input.end();

       bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,p,s);

       if (ok)   std::cout << "Parse success\n";
       else      std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
       if (f!=l) std::cout << "Remaining input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
   }
   ```
2. Secondly, the skipper has nothing to with things:

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a06c7615233a027a)</kbd>** fails just as badly:

   ```
   #include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
   #include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi.hpp>

   namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

   template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper = qi::ascii::space_type>
   struct Grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, Skipper> {
       Grammar() : Grammar::base_type(expression) { }
   private:
       qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> const
           // Tokens
           scalar_literal { qi::uint_ | qi::int_ },
           identifier     { qi::lexeme[(qi::alpha | '_') >> *(qi::alnum | '_')] },
           // Rules
           operand        { (scalar_literal | identifier | ('(' >> expression >> ')')) },
           expression     { operand };
   };

   int main() {
       using It = std::string::const_iterator;
       Grammar<It> p;
       std::string const input = "(123)";

       It f = input.begin(), l = input.end();

       bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,p,qi::ascii::space);

       if (ok)   std::cout << "Parse success\n";
       else      std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
       if (f!=l) std::cout << "Remaining input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
   }
   ```
3. Thirdly, the timing of initialization has to do with it:

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dccd002aafe94f1b)</kbd>** succeeds:

   ```
   #include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
   #include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi.hpp>

   namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

   template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper = qi::ascii::space_type>
   struct Grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, Skipper> {
       Grammar() : Grammar::base_type(expression) { 
           scalar_literal = qi::uint_ | qi::int_;
           identifier     = (qi::alpha | '_') >> *(qi::alnum | '_');
           // Rules
           operand        = (scalar_literal | identifier | ('(' >> expression >> ')'));
           expression     = operand;
       }
   private:
       qi::rule<Iterator>          scalar_literal, identifier; // Tokens
       qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> operand,        expression; // Rules
   };

   int main() {
       using It = std::string::const_iterator;
       Grammar<It> p;
       std::string const input = "(123)";

       It f = input.begin(), l = input.end();

       bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,p,qi::ascii::space);

       if (ok)   std::cout << "Parse success\n";
       else      std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
       if (f!=l) std::cout << "Remaining input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
   }
   ```

   Prints

   ```
   Parse success
   ```
4. Finally, you can have all the cake and eat it too:

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74539c416e20fb19)</kbd>**

   ```
   #include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
   #include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi.hpp>

   namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

   namespace parsing {
       namespace detail {
           template <typename Iterator>
           struct Skipper : qi::grammar<Iterator> {
               Skipper() : Skipper::base_type(_skip_rule) {
                   _comment  = boost::spirit::repository::confix("/*", "*/")    [*(qi::char_ - "*/")]     // Multi-line
                           | boost::spirit::repository::confix("//", qi::eol) [*(qi::char_ - qi::eol)]  // Single-line
                           ;

                   _skip_rule = qi::ascii::space | _comment;
               }
           private:
               qi::rule<Iterator> _comment, _skip_rule;
           };

           template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper = Skipper<Iterator> >
           struct Grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, Skipper> {
               Grammar() : Grammar::base_type(expression) {
                   scalar_literal = qi::uint_ | qi::int_;
                   identifier     = (qi::alpha | '_') >> *(qi::alnum | '_');
                   // Rules
                   operand        = (scalar_literal | identifier | ('(' >> expression >> ')'));
                   expression     = operand;
               }
           private:
               qi::rule<Iterator>          scalar_literal, identifier; // Tokens
               qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> operand,        expression; // Rules
           };
       }

       template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper = detail::Skipper<Iterator> >
       struct facade {
           template <typename Range> static bool parse(Range const& input) {
               Iterator f = boost::begin(input), l = boost::end(input);
               bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, _parser, _skipper);

               if (f!=l)
                   std::cout << "Remaining input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";

               return ok;
           }

       private:
           static const detail::Skipper<Iterator>          _skipper;
           static const detail::Grammar<Iterator, Skipper> _parser;
       };

       template <class I, class S> const detail::Skipper<I>    facade<I,S>::_skipper = {};
       template <class I, class S> const detail::Grammar<I, S> facade<I,S>::_parser  = {};
   }

   int main() {
       using It = std::string::const_iterator;
       std::string const input = "(123)";

       bool ok = parsing::facade<It>::parse(input);

       if (ok)   std::cout << "Parse success\n";
       else      std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
   }
   ```

Note that the result is the same, the parser/skipper are every bit as static and const as in the original code, the code is a lot easier to maintain (and has a bit more structure to it at the same time).

---

This is basically where the Singletons-are-bad theme meets the inner-const-is-problematic theme. You don't need to make the fields const. You don't need to make the instances static.

Just, create only one instance if you prefer. Also, it's not a problem that the parser is now copyable (you don't have to copy it; but now you can).

Comment: Thanks a lot! But one more question: if I try to initialize rules outside of the constructor's body:

`Grammar() :
scalar_literal(qi::uint_ | qi::int_),
identifier((qi::alpha | '_') >> *(qi::alnum | '_')),
operand((scalar_literal | identifier | ('(' >> expression >> ')'))),
expression(operand),
Grammar::base_type(expression)`
I got a warning that _expression_ will be initialized after _base_type_ call. Then parsing fails. So the rules MUST be assigned ONLY inside the constructor's body? Or is there a way to change initialization order?

Comment: Not respective to the base: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Initialization_order and http://stackoverflow.com/a/2669911/85371. I think the true reason here is the difference between assignment and (copy) initialization. I'm not motivated to find out the difference though :) Just stick to the common idioms. Inner-const is not very useful anyways.