# C++ - order of member initialization and incrementation

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I was looking for some tests to improve my C++ knowledge. Here is one of the exercises: What is the output of the following program?

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A(int n = 0) : m_i(n)
    {
        std::cout << m_i;
        ++m_i;
    }

protected:
    int m_i;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(int n = 5) : m_a(new A[2]), m_x(++m_i) { std::cout << m_i; }

    ~B() { delete [] m_a; }

private:
    A m_x;
    A *m_a;
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Well, I tried this code, and the answer is `02002`. I come here to have some explanation because I don't understand why `02002` is the result.
I will explain my reasoning, but could some tell me where am I wrong please?

Let's call "str" the current string to print. When the `b` object is built:

1. The constructor of `A` is called. str => `0`, `m_i` => `1`
2. Construction of `m_a(new A[2])`. str => `000`
3. Construction of `m_x(++m_i)`. str => `0002`, `m_i` => `3`
4. Last update of str (in `B`'s constructor) => str => `00023`

**Here are my questions:**

- Why is the final value of `m_i` `2` and not `3`?
- Why is the construction of `m_x(++m_i)` done before the one of `m_a(new A[2])`? I tried to exchange the position of the initialization of m_x and m_a and the answer is still the same : `02002`.

Comment: Since `m_x` is declared *before*  `m_a` in the `B` class, `B(int n = 5) : m_a(new A[2]), m_x(++m_i)` is ill-formed and should be `B(int n = 5) : m_x(++m_i), m_a(new A[2])`.

Comment: @YSC is correct, at least, you will get a ton of warning when compile with gcc (I'm not sure about the others)

Comment: @YSC `B(int n = 5) : m_a(new A[2]), m_x(++m_i)` is not ill-formed. Perhaps it should be made ill-formed, but unfortunately it isn't.

Comment: you're right, with warnings i get: "test.cpp:27: warning: ‘B::m_a’ will be initialized after"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why is the final value of `m_i` `2` and not `3`?

Because `new A[2]` creates two separate instances having nothing to do with `*this`. `m_i` of the `b` instance is only incremented in `A::A` and `B::B` (twice).

<sup>If incrementation of `m_i` should be performed on the same instance (`m_i` being a reference, for example), it would be more reasonable to think that the final value of `m_i` should be `4` (there are two objects in the array - two additional increments).</sup>

> Why is the construction of `m_x(++m_i)` done before the one of `m_a(new A[2])`?

Because [the order of initialization depends on the order of declaration of the data members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669888/c-initialization-order-for-member-classes), not the order in which you write initializations in the member initializer list.

Comment: Thx for the answer ! I just understood why 2 and not 3. i also add one more incrementation during the construction of m_x.

Comment: @Ptiseb Some compilers (MingW and VC) issues warnings if you initialize members in different order than you declared them.

Answer (score 4):

When you construct `b` the `A` part of `B` is constructed first.  This gives the `0` in the output.  Then we get the `2` because `m_x(++m_i)` happens first since `m_x` is listed first in the class.  Since `m_i` is 1 from the `A` part of `B` being constructed `++m_i` gives `2` and now we have `02`.  Then `m_a(new A[2])` is ran which gives us 2 `0`(one for each memeber of the array).  That puts us at `0200`.  We then get the final `2` from `{ std::cout << m_i; }` since `m_i` is still `2` from `m_x(++m_i)`.