# Destructor and Constructor Ordering in C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have a short block of code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class C {
public:
    C() {i = 6; cout << "C0:" << i << endl;}

    C(int i0) {i = i0; cout << "C1:" << i << endl;}

    ~C() {cout << "C2:" << i << endl;}
private:
    int i;
};

class D {
public:
    D() {cout << "D0" << endl;}
    ~D() {cout << "D1" << endl;}
private:
    C c;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cout << "X" << endl;
    D d;
    cout << "Y" << endl;
}
```

The output of which is:

```
X
C0:6
D0
Y
D1
C2:6
```

My question is: **why would the `C0:6` be created *before* the `D0` in this case?**

I know that for an inherited class, the order is Base Constructor->Derived Constructor->Derived Destructor->Base Destructor. So, if `D` was inherited from `C`, then I would expect the ordering here. However, `D` is *not* a subclass of `C`, from what I can tell; it simply contains an instance of the `C` class.

So in this case, why do I get the same output ordering as if `D` was a subclass of `C`?

There's clearly a fundamental rule I'm not understanding.

Comment: The data members constructed first, then the constructor of the class itself is called.

Comment: Try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669888/c-initialization-order-for-member-classes

Comment: Okay, this is what I think I'm taking away from that post: If a class contains other classes, those other classes will have their constructors called first. However, the initial class will still have its destructor called first. Is that correct?

Comment: Think about it for a moment -- if one of your member subobjects was a vector, your constructor might like to add some items to it.  But that wouldn't be possible if the vector hadn't been constructed yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base class objects and member variables (in that order) are initialized before the statements in the constructor body are executed.

`c` is a member of `D`, so you see `c`'s initialization before `D`'s constructor body.

Destruction occurs in the opposite order of construction.

Comment: Worth noting that base class objects and (non-static) member variables are collectively called "subobjects", and get similar treatment in many ways.  The differences lead to the "Inheritance vs Composition" question, exactly because they are so nearly interchangable.