# why constructor of base class invokes first?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

While running the code below, why is the constructor of the base class is derived first even if we first declare an object of derive class.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class base {
  public:
    base()
    { cout<<"Constructing base \n"; }
    ~base()
    { cout<<"Destructing base \n"; }
};

class derived: public base {
  public:
    derived()
    { cout<<"Constructing derived \n"; }
    ~derived()
    { cout<<"Destructing derived \n"; }
};

int main(void)
{
  derived *d = new derived(); //d is defined ahead of the base class object
  base *b = d;
  delete b;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What else would you expect and why exactly?

Comment: Hint: There is a `base` **sub-object** inside `derived`.

Comment: Question is not clear. Can you explain?

Comment: Note that your `delete` causes undefined behaviour due to lack of `virtual ~base()`.

Comment: Objects are constructed bottom-up. `derived` has a base class of type `base`, so when you create an instance of `derived` you see a chain of constructors calls like: `base` -> `derived`. How would you put a roof on a house the walls of which are not in place yet? Bottom-up. That's all.

Comment: i am asking why is it not printing the constructor of the derived class since we first created an object of derived class

Comment: Please check class data initialization rules [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669888/c-initialization-order-of-class-data-members).

Comment: @samfisher It prints _constructing base_ and then _constructing derived_, for you **must** initialize a `base` object first of all if you want to create a `derived` one. The former is a sub-object of the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inheritance expresses an "is-a" relationship, so that all objects of class `derived` ARE objects of class `base`. `derived` objects have all of the data and methods that `base` objects do, plus the data and methods explicitly declared in the `derived` class declaration.

It's perfectly possible (and common) to write `Derived` classes that depend on the implementation of their `Base` classes. For example, suppose that we have

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() { n = 5; }
    int GetN() const { return n; }
private:
    int n;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() { m = GetN() * 2; }
    int GetM() const { return m; }
private:
    int m;
};
```

Now we'd expect

```
Derived* d = new Derived();
std::cout << d->GetM() << std::endl;
```

to print `10`, which is exactly what it should do (barring any mistakes on my part). This is a totally reasonable (if a little contrived) thing to do.

The only way the language can get code like this to work properly is to run the `Base` constructor before the `Derived` constructor when constructing an object of type `Derived`. This is because the `Derived` constructor depends on being able to call the `GetN()` method, which it inherits from `Base`, the proper functioning of which depends on the data member `n` having been properly initialised in the `Base` constructor.

To summarise, when constructing any `Derived` object, C++ must construct it as a `Base` object first because `Derived` is-a `Base` and will generally depend on it's implementation and data.

When you do

```
base* b = d;
```

in your code, you're declaring a variable `b` that is of type "pointer to a `base` object" and then initialising this variable with the same memory address held in `d`. The compiler doesn't mind you doing this because all `derived` objects ARE `base` objects, so it makes sense that you might want to treat `d` as a `b`. Nothing actually happens to the object here though, it's simply a declaration and instantiation of a pointer variable. The object pointed to by `d` already was a `base` object, since all `derived` objects are base objects.

Note that this explanation is intentionally a little fuzzy round the edges and is nowhere near a full explanation of the relationship between base and derived classes in C++. You'll want to go looking in other articles/books/the standard for that. I hope this is relatively easy to understand for beginners though.