# C++ reference to nowhere

Tags: c++, reference, undefined-behavior

Thinking of this question [Why can I initialize reference member with data member before initializing the data member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51426240/why-can-i-initialize-reference-member-with-data-member-before-initializing-the-d?noredirect=1#comment89824762_51426240) as well as this [Why is initialization of a new variable by itself valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152298/why-is-initialization-of-a-new-variable-by-itself-valid) following strange code came to my mind:

```
int main()
{
    int &ri = ri;
    ri = 0;
}
```

This code compiles [live demo](https://ideone.com/trvt5h), I know this is UB, but just wonder, what happens inside compiler, where this reference actually points to?

Update: different situation happens when that reference is global: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'int+main()%0A%7B%0A++++int+%26ri+%3D+ri%3B%0A++++ri+%3D+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g81,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), gcc seems to declare it as a pointer and make it to point to itself

Note for downvoters: I know this code is invalid and I am not expecting particular behavior from a compiler, but I think looking inside may help to understand why following code is not illegal and how references work in the language:

```
struct foo {
    int &ri = i;
    int i = 0;
};
```

or this:

```
 extern int i;
 int &ri = i;
 int i = 0;
```

Update2: while assignment is definitely UB, it is a good question, if declaration itself:

```
int &ri = ri;
```

is UB or not. This seem to be is pure evil - `ri` cannot be used in any way, but declaration itself seems to be vaild.

Comment: You've already stated that you know it's UB. By definition, we can't tell you what an arbitrary compiler does.

Comment: If you can read some x86 assembly, this compiler might help you: https://godbolt.org

Comment: You can check the assembly [here](https://godbolt.org/g/qXMUQt)

Comment: The reference refers to an object that's strikingly similar to the one those dangling pointers point to.

Comment: clang++ -O generates an invalid opcode because it recognized the UB :-)

Comment: @PaulR: I would be more impressed if it raised an error, considering all paths lead to UB.

Comment: The whole idea of labeling a certain construct as "undefined behaviour" is that compiler builders *do not have to take this construct into account*. Most importantly, they do not have to have a *defined* behaviour when facing *undefined* behaviour in your code...

Comment: @DevSolar maybe I did not make myself clear, but point is I do not want to use such code and do not want to rely on particular behavior. I just wonder what happens under the hood there and understanding it may help me to understand  the language better.

Comment: @Slava: The point is that the behaviour is *undefined*. The compiler might crash on even days in the month and emit a beep on uneven days. It might enter a non-terminating loop. It might start writing zeroes into the object file until it runs out of disk space. The only way to really figure it out is to try -- and remember that the next version of the compiler might "handle" the situation another way entirely.

Comment: There is no "understanding of the language" to be found here. The behaviour is *not defined by the language*. You're off the chart.

Comment: @DevSolar so what? Instead it produced assembly and looking into it helped me to understand some things better. This is what SO for, is it not?

Comment: @Slava: No, the *correct* answer is "the behaviour is undefined". You can look up what a *specific* compiler in a *specific* version does with a *specific* piece of code where this occurs, but *that has nothing to do with the language C++*. It is a detail of how said compiler reacts to erroneous input.

Comment: It is equivalent to `int* p = p; *p = 0;`. It should issue an _`uninitialized local variable used`_ warning, at least.

Comment: Answering my own question: `int value = createValueAndRememberPointer(&value);`

Comment: @ZDF kind of, but it would not compile on C++ without cast. But there is bigger difference - unlike pointer reference does not have to be represented in memory at all, which makes it so hmm strange.

Comment: @DevSolar fine, but whole concept that reference as an alias (which does not exist in memory) pointing to itself is so funny I could not resist to ask about it.

Comment: @Slava: ...and because it's so "funny" (a.k.a. not making sense), no behaviour is defined for this case. See, it's a snake biting it's own tail, really.

Comment: @DevSolar I know that behaviour is not defined, some questions do not need answers, they are good by themselves. I think this one is just good to think about, if community disagree, I am fine with that.

Comment: With your edits you're just making it *more* unlikely to get a good answer. The `struct foo` construct is, for example, legal for a very specific reason -- but  completely unrelated to the rest of your question.

Comment: @DevSolar actually after some thoughts - while assignment is definetly UB, this declaration is not IMHO, so it can be analyzed and discussed

Comment: "good just to think about" - so it's like a C++ koan? This kind of thing might be informative when you're looking at a given compiler implementation (although I'm still not sure it's _useful_ information), but it's just not correct to suggest it tells you anything about the language.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just a long comment.

I do not know what you mean by *"...it would not compile on C++ without cast..."*.

How references must be implemented, it is not specified as far as I know. However, they must be pointers in disguise (what else could they be?). The [references source](https://godbolt.org/g/qXMUQt) and the [pointers source](https://godbolt.org/g/2ZmvzK) will generate **exactly the same code**.

*"...does not have to be represented in memory at all,..."* I am not sure I understand what this means. The address of a reference is the address of the object it refers to. Therefore you might say the **reference itself has no address**. The [following](https://www.ideone.com/IlT06J) will print `i`'s address twice:

```
int i;
int &ri = i;
cout << &ri << endl << &i;
```

Since the language **allows the use of uninitialized variables**, I think a good compiler **must issue an warning but not an error**: *`uninitialized variable used`*.

**[EDIT]**

I had a short discussion with someone involved in the design of C++ (I forgot to ask permission to name him). In short, banning `T x = x;` is desirable, but **C++ was not designed from scratch: it had to be backward compatible with C**.

So, you found a **legal** way to create an uninitialized reference. The answer to *"...where this reference actually points to?"* is: where an uninitialized pointer points.

Comment: "...it would not compile on C++ without cast...". I actually thought about `int *p = &p;`, my confusion

Comment: "...does not have to be represented in memory at all,..." I am not sure I understand what this means.  I mean when you declare a pointer, it is represented as a variable in memory, but reference does not have  to, as it can be just another name for a variable.

Comment: "I think a good compiler must issue an warning but not an error: uninitialized variable used" disagree, unlike other cases you cannot make this reference initialized at all, it is completely broken and self contained

Comment: _"...completely broken and self contained "_ `int i = i;` is legal and so it is `int& ri = ri;`. The only thing you can tell when you reach the initialization point is whether the initializer is initialized.  See the edit.

Comment: No `int i = i;` is not legal, as you read from uninitialized variable, which is UB (at least for local variables)

Comment: UB does not equal illegal. `int i = i;` is legal for the name is in scope before the start of the initializer (C rule). The compiler should warn you about using an uninitialized variable (`= i`). On my compiler I get a warning or an error - depends on settings.

Comment: "UB does not equal illegal" it is matter on what you mean by illegal. Anyway what I meant is `int &ri = ri;` is not even UB, unlike `int i = i;`, at least I think it is not.

Comment: I agree this is not right, and so does the gentleman I was talking to, but it is legal and it cannot be changed for it will break the backward C compatibility (and, I guess, it is not desirable to treat the reference case differently). After all why not live with it? I didn't get warnings for using uninitialized variables for years - to me these warnings look like recent additions :o).