# Is it Undefined Behavior to initialize a member data from another member data declared after it?

Tags: c++, oop

If I have class that has two member data `x_` and `y_` declared so that `x_` is initialized from `y_` and `y_` has a value then is `x_` has an `Undefined value`? or what?

```
class Empl {
    public:
        int x_{ y_ };
        int y_{ 10 };
};

int main(){

    Empl e{};
    std::cout << e.x_ << ", " << e.y_ << std::endl;

}
```

I tried the example on MSVC++ 2105 and got: `0` and `10` while on GCC I got `10` and `10`!

So as a result is it undefined behavior to do so?

Comment: C++ requires (or used to require) `x` initialization first, and then `y` initialization second because that's the order they are declared. GCC is probably optimizing what it sees as a constexpr. As to the UB, it is probable. Compile and run with `-fsanitize=undefined`.

Comment: they are [initialized in the order they are declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669888/c-initialization-order-of-class-data-members)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So as a result is it undefined behavior to do so?

Yes. The behaviour of reading an indeterminate value is undefined. In this example, `y_` has indeterminate value when its value is used to initialise `x_`, because it is initialised after `x_`. It is initialised after `x_` because members are initialised in order of declaration.