# Order of initialization of class member variables

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list

Consider the following code snippet:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int a, int b) : j(a), i(j + b) {}
    int i, j;
};

int main()
{
    A a(10, 20);
    std::cout << a.i << " " << a.j << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The standard [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2669911/2912665) that the order of initialization of the member variables is the order in which they are declared. In this case, `i` will be initialized before `j`. Since `j` isn't initialized yet, `i = *a garbage value* + 20`, and then `j` is initialized with `10`.

The code [prints](http://cpp.sh/2mvwc) `20 10`.

i.e., `j` was considered to be `0` when calculating `i`.

Does the standard guarantee to use default values for built-in types in such a scenario? Or is it just that the garbage value happened to be `0`? Or is it *undefined behavior*?

Comment: "Or is it just that the garbage value happened to be 0?" - Probably in over 90% of the cases this (still UB of course).

Comment: *Or is it undefined behavior?* Yes.

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6032889/5728381

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the standard guarantee to use default values for built-in types in such a scenario?

No. The value is indeterminate in this case.

> Or is it undefined behavior?

Yes. The behaviour of reading an indeterminate value is undefined (except for narrow character types IIRC).

Answer (score 1):

`j + b` is undefined behavior, because it uses an indeterminate value (that of `j` before its initialization) outside of one of the specific instances where doing so is allowed (all of which relate to `char` variants and `std::byte`, not `int`, indeterminate values).

In C++20 it will also have undefined behavior, because you are accessing `j` outside its lifetime. From what I can tell in C++17 and before the lifetime of `j` begins with allocation of its storage, because the initialization of `j` is *vacuous*. The definitions of vacuous initialization and lifetime change in C++20, though.

So in any case use of a variable before it is initialized is very ill-advised.