# C++ Member Initializer Lists Problem: Declaration Order on Private Member Variables

Tags: c++, class, private, member, initializer

This is my first ever question posted on Stack Overflow, hope someone could explain it.
So basically the two classes are the same except the order of the private member variables. The output is `10 20 10 0` I cannot understand why the order of declaration affects the output.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass(int value): b(value), a(b * 2){
        cout << b << " " << a << " ";
    }
private:
    int b;
    int a;
};

class YourClass{
public:
    YourClass(int value): d(value), c(d * 2){
        cout << d << " " << c << " ";
    }
private:
    int c;
    int d;
};

int main(){
    MyClass obj(10);
    YourClass OBJ(10);
}
```

Comment: Because [order matters](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#ctor-initializer-order) and you should get a warning about this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2dc06f1a6801bb90

Comment: Class data members are initialized in the order of their declaration inside the class, not in the order you specify by constructor initializer list. For YourClass, c will be initialized before initialization of d, but it uses d, so basically you have undefined behavior when initializing c.

Comment: _I cannot understand why the order of declaration affects the output._ This is simply because the C++ standard specifies so: http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#13.3.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class members are initialized in the order of their declaration.

[Initialization Order of Class Data Members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669888/initialization-order-of-class-data-members)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass(int value): b(value++), a(value++){
        std::cout << b << " " << a << " " << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int b;
    int a;
};

class YourClass{
public:
    YourClass(int value): b(value++), a(value++){
        std::cout << b << " " << a << " " << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int a;
    int b;

};

int main(){
    MyClass obj(10);
    YourClass OBJ(10);
}
```

Output:

```
10 11
11 10
```

Comment: Thanks! value++ is really helpful